# Creating a static variable within a generic interface that returns the said interface (or at least in a mapper in Spring)

Tags: java, spring, generics, mapper

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper extends BasicMapper<User, UserDto> {
    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
}
```

and generic interface which unsurprisingly looks like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface BasicMapper<Entity, Dto extends AbstractDto> {
    // This is something I'd like to have, but it doesn't work :(
    // BasicMapper<Entity, Dto> INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BasicMapper<Entity, Dto>.getClass());
    // (Skipped ordinary methods...)
}
```

It works, but I'm trying to push static variable `INSTANCE` into generic `BasicMapper` interface. Is it possible or if not, what's best workaround? I would prefer a generic answer that doesn't rely on Spring and annotations, but if not possible, I'll settle for best workaround that works with String and `@Mapper` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually solve problems like this is using a FACTORY

```
public static final User_Mapper createUserMapper() {
  User_Mapper um = new User_Mapper();
  um.INSTANCE = appers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't implement or even instantiate the object. In specified interface it is `org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper` method that does instantiating.